# How to Pass Json object in GET url query string

Tags: javascript, json, spring-mvc, get, request

I have a json object in javascript,

```
filters = Object {assetType: "CAR~LIGHT TRUCK", bodyType: "SEDAN~SPORT UTIL"}
```

I need to pass these values along with 5 more string value in query string.

```
url = '/starHome/exportToCsv/'+tier+'/?period='+period+'&level2='+level2+'&level3='+level3+'&level4='+level4+'&filters='+filters;
```

**window.location.href = url;**
when I tried to get filter parameter value in controller
`request.getparamter("filters");` I get "`[object object]`"

how can I pass this value to controller?.
I have a pojo class contains all these fields. Can I make use of that class?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Everyone,
I have used `JSON.stringify(filters);`
and in controller

```
String filtersString = request.getParameter("filters");
Map<String,Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(filtersString, HashMap.class);
```

Kindly reply back, if there s a better approach.

Answer (score 8):

I found the following as the best solution so far using Javasript

```
var a = {a:'foo',b:[1,2,3],g: {q:"8798"}};

var b = window.btoa(JSON.stringify(a)); 

console.log(b) // output eyJhIjoiZm9vIiwiYiI6WzEsMiwzXSwiZyI6eyJxIjoiODc5OCJ9fQ

// restore b again 
console.log(JSON.parse(window.atob(b))); // output : {a:'foo',b:[1,2,3],g: {q:"8798"}}
```

Comment: you are restoring b in java script itself. My question was to get them in back end controller.

Comment: Oops , I missed this one , but in general still the same principle you can decode the base64 string in java then parse it as JSONObject

Answer (score 4):

You can encode your json string in base64 and then use it in the url:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa

Comment: {window.btoa(filters);} is not helping.

Comment: @gauti what do you mean with is not helping?

Comment: I'm not able to decode the value as Map in controller.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var filters = {assetType: "CAR~LIGHT TRUCK", bodyType: "SEDAN~SPORT UTIL"};
    filters = jQuery.param( filters );
    console.log("filters ", filters );
    //filters  assetType=CAR~LIGHT+TRUCK&bodyType=SEDAN~SPORT+UTIL

    url = '/starHome/exportToCsv/'+tier+'/?period='+period+'&level2='+level2+'&level3='+level3+'&level4='+level4+'&filters='+filters;
    </script>
```

Comment: jQuery.param() is fine, but is there a way that I can get that value into a Map<String,Object> in controller?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the encodeURI and decodeURI functions.
First, we encode the JSON string so that it won't cause any issues in the URL.
When we get the value back, we decode the string and then parse its JSON.

In this approach, the content is human readable and parsable at the backend without too much effort.

```
const values = {prices:[1,2,3], sale: true, minAmount: 500 };
const json = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(values));
const result = JSON.parse(decodeURI(json));
```